# Dictionary<string, List<string>> has all values same as that of the last entered value

Tags: c#, list, generics, dictionary

I am having a dictionary of string as key and List as value.

And adding the entry in the following manner:-

```
allDDLs = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
List<string> temp;
temp = ddlData.get("INV_DDL_Access_Mechanism", "Type");
allDDLs.Add("Access_Mechanism", temp);
temp = ddlData.get("INV_DDL_Application_Operating_System", "OS_Name");
```

Like this, there are 18 entries. But when I debugged the code, I found that all the values are same as that of the last entered value. But the keys are fine.

For example, when I get the value for "INV_DDL_Access_Mechanism", I get the value same as that of for "INV_DDL_Application_Operating_System".

I don't know what is wrong with it. Any help would be appreciated. :-)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**
Code for accessing the Dictionary values:

```
List<string> listOfColumns = allDDLs.Keys.ToList<string>();


for(int i = 0; i < listOfColumns.Count(); ++i) {
     string columnName = listOfColumns[i].ToString();
     List<string> tempDDL = new List<string>();
     tempDDL = allDDLs[columnName];
     List<string> columnValues = DataColumnToList(columnName, excelDataSet.Tables[0]);
     for (int j = 0; j < columnValues.Count(); ++j ) {
          if (!tempDDL.Contains(columnValues[j])) {
              errorReport.Rows[j][columnName.ToString()] = columnValues[j].ToString() + "LOLOLOL";
          }
     }        
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Code of "get" method.

```
public List<string> get(string tableName, string parameter) {
        ds.Clear();
        valuesForDDL.Clear();
        ds = objDatabase.ByText("Select distinct " + parameter + " from " + tableName + " where Del_Status = 'Available'");
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
            valuesForDDL.Add(row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
        }
        return valuesForDDL;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you set INV_DDL_Application_Operating_System and INV_DDL_Access_Mechanism. What is ddlData?

Comment: @TheCodeKing: I know what you may be pointing at. The code of get(TableName, ColumnName) is working fine. I have tested that part. :-). It will return any duplicate lists. I clear the list in that code before adding new items to it. And then return the list.

Comment: You haven't shown any code that is useful for helping you with your problem.

Comment: @ivorykoder - surely you need a loop somewhere to populate your dictionary... where is that code?

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to the smallest size you can that reproduces the problem. Post it here. Someone will tell you where the bug is. Make sure it compiles.

Comment: @cjk: I have posted the code you demanded.

Comment: I have run that "get" method in Debug mode by applying the breakpoint at the return statement. It is returning new list on every call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with your `get` method.

On every call to `get` you return `valuesForDDL`, and then on next call you clear it and repopulate it. See the bug yet?

`valuesForDDL` must NOT be a field. This is akin to having a global state, and global state kills. Make it local and your code will work.

```
public List<string> get(string tableName, string parameter) {
        var valuesForDDL = new List<Whatever>();
        var ds = objDatabase.ByText("Select distinct " + parameter + " from " + tableName + " where Del_Status = 'Available'");
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
            valuesForDDL.Add(row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
        }
        return valuesForDDL;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Orthogonal note: With LINQ, you can make this code look much more nicer. I'll refactor your code as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get(string tableName, string parameter) {
  var ds = objDatabase.ByText("Select distinct " + parameter + 
    " from " + tableName + " where Del_Status = 'Available'");
  return ds.Tables[0].Rows.Select(row => row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Same goes for `ds`. Make that local as well.

Comment: I have run that "get" method in Debug mode by applying the breakpoint at the return statement. It is returning new list on every call.

So, the problem is not with "get" method.

Comment: @ivorykoder: You get the impression that it is returning a new list on every call, but when in fact it is modifying the single list - the one referenced by `valuesForDDL` every time you make a call to `get`.

Comment: @ivorykoder: Try making the change I suggested. Trust me, it will work. :-)

Comment: I have used that method before also, its working fine for any number of calls.

Answer (score 3):

You said in your comment:

> I clear the list in that code before adding new items to it. And then return the list.

This could be the problem, ... if you return the *same* `List<string>` in every call of `ddlData.get()` (using an instance/static field or property) and you just do a `List<string>.Clear()` you *overwrite* the content of the last returned list.

In your `ddlData.get()` you should do a `new List<string>()` instead of `Clear()`ing an existing list.

If that isn't your problem, please post more code (especially the ddlData.get() method, or the whole class).

Comment: +1 was about to post the same, the issue is surely in the get method.

Comment: @ulrichb: That is not the problem. I have run that "get" method in Debug mode by applying the breakpoint at the return statement. It is returning new list on every call.

Comment: @ivorykoder: No, you don't see a *new* list on every return of your `get()`-method, but you see the *same list-instance* with *different content* (e.g. different list items).

Answer (score -1):

You are using the same instance of List ("temp" in your code).

Instantiate a new

```
List<string>
```

for each `dllData.get("....` and it'll be just fine.

```
List<string> temp1 = ddlData.get("INV_DDL_Access_Mechanism", "Type");    
List<string> temp2 = ddlData.get("INV_DDL_Application_Operating_System", "OS_Name");
....
allDDLs.Add("Access_Mechanism", temp1);
allDDLs.Add("Application_Operating_System", temp2);
```

**EDIT**

You would prefer not using temp variables, so use:

```
allDDLs.Add("Access_Mechanism", ddlData.get("INV_DDL_Access_Mechanism", "Type"));
allDDLs.Add("Application_Operating_System", ddlData.get("INV_DDL_Application_Operating_System", "OS_Name"));
```

If `ddlData.get(...)` creates a new `List<string>` each time, it'll work for sure.

Comment: This is wrong, introducing variables like that won't have any different effect.

Comment: No, `ddlData.get` would return a different object every time, it doesn't matter whether it is assigned to one variable or multiple

Comment: ddlData.get returns different object every time, but introducing new variables allows to store the different instances returned by ddlData.get....

You could use allDDLs.Add("Access_Mechanism", ddlData.get("INV_DDL_Access_Mechanism", "Type"));
if you prefer....